# Keeping some choices in the Table for the Field of Type Dropdown

Tags: mysql

i am having a Table named

Attributes

which has

```
    id form_id label size sequence_no   Type

    1    1      Name 200    1           Text
    2    1      Age  150    2           Number
    3    1     Address 300  3           Textarea
    4    1     Gender   200 4           Dropdown
```

I am having the doubt how can i keep the Choices of the Field of type "Dropdown" in the Table
Eg. For Gender the choices will Male , Female..

Please give me the suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

edit :

you can add another type to this table call dropdown_choice,
and add all the choices of this dropdown to this table,
need to keep in another field  the master id of this dropdown choice.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a child table like this:

```
id  value_id  sequence_no  label
4   100       1            Male
4   101       2            Female
```

Note where `id = 4` is all the values for the #4 question.

Comment: Pretty much what i have. I prefer to put an auto_increment id to make updating/deleting easier.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to build an automagic form that is built from a database?

I would suggest having that table be something like elements and have another table for options which links back to the original id

i.e.

```
options
id    element_id   value    text
1      4            1       Male
2      4            2       Female
```

That way for specific types you will be know to look up the options.

You may want another field to specify if its a multiselect or perhaps you could make it another Type.